# NextJs 13 State Management with Redux toolkit

Tags: javascript, next.js, next.js13

I am using NextJs 13 with app directory, and I am using the redux toolkit to manage a search state from a client component and render filtered data to a server side component. The issue that I have is when I search the store is updating but it's not affecting to the screen, I mean not rendering the result.
You can check the codes below:

**App Home Page:**

```
const getListPokemon = async (): Promise<PokemonLink[]> => {
  const response = await fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=100");
  const data = await response.json();
  return data.results;
};
export default async function Home() {
  const pokemons = await getListPokemon();
  store.dispatch(setPokemons(pokemons));

  return (
    <main className="h-screen ">
      <Preloader Pokemons={pokemons} />
      <PokemonsList />
    </main>
  );
}
```

**PokemonsList**

```
const PokemonsList = () => {
  const PokemonData = store.getState().searchReducer.pokemons;
  return (
    <div className="container grid grid-cols-2 gap-4 py-4 mx-auto sm:grid-cols-3 md:grid-cols-4">
      {PokemonData.map((pokemon: PokemonLink, index) => {
        return (
          /* @ts-expect-error Server Component */
          <PokemonCard pokemonUrl={pokemon.url} key={index} />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Preloader**

```
export default function Preloader({ Pokemons }: { Pokemons: PokemonLink[] }) {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  const loaded = useRef(false);
  if (!loaded.current) {
    dispatch(setPokemons(Pokemons));
    loaded.current = true;
  }
  return null;
}
```

**Search Slice**

```
const initialState: InitialState = {
  search: "",
  pokemons: [],
  data: [],
};
const searchPokemonSlice = createSlice({
  name: "search",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setSearch: (state, action: PayloadAction<string>) => {
      state.search = action.payload;
    },
    setPokemons: (state, action: PayloadAction<PokemonLink[]>) => {
      state.data = action.payload;
      state.pokemons = state.data;
    },
    searchForPokemon: (state) => {
      const searchQuery = state.search.toLowerCase();
      state.pokemons = state.data.filter((item) => {
        return item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery);
      });
    },
  },
});

export const { setSearch, setPokemons, searchForPokemon } =
  searchPokemonSlice.actions;
export default searchPokemonSlice.reducer;
```

I want to the search result be refreshed to the screen.